# How can I be sure that all my data is sent and received on the CAN-bus?

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I am using can-bus on the stm32f3 and transmitter. I send and receive data over a 1Mb/s can-bus line populated with 2 devices.

I analysed the line with an oscilloscope and detected no problem. But how can I make sure each data sent is received ?

Answer (score 2):

If you observed via the oscilloscope that messages were being transmitted then if you want to be sure that all your data is being transmitted, you should handle the bus errors. If there is no error, everything is being transmitted.

For more information on CAN Bus Error Handling, see [here](https://www.kvaser.com/about-can/the-can-protocol/can-error-handling/)

Comment: there is two devices yes you are right but if we have 20 canbus devices. How can I determine the which canbus device couldnt catch message from the transmitter ? Which one couldn get the message? (Message send by broadcast)

Comment: The CAN-bus is a broadcast bus, this mean that if one device couldn't "get" the message, none could have.

Comment: For example I have 4 devices on the canbus line and 1 transmitter device total 5 device in the line. Transmitter sending message but, device 3 couldnt get message, other device working. does this mean that the message is not forwarded to any of them?

Comment: There is no forwarding on a bus, they all get the same message at the same time. If all except one device receive a message then the problem doesn't come from the bus. Do you have the some code running on each device? If not then the one running on the device no 3 might be faulty.

Comment: Suppose there is no code other than tx engaged on connected devices. Can't they even get the message on other devices because of a malfunction in one device?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here and we are move away from programming concern. But yes, it is possible that there is a malfunction on one of your devices and if the device wasn't publishing periodic messages on the bus, you wouldn't be able to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

you may define a counter (1,2,3 ..) and check the arrival of all number on the other side.

Comment: Is there any other way of making sure I can miss the data until I make a comparison that the 1 mbits will also have a buffer problem too quickly?

Comment: Otherway is to calculate a checksum and at the end of transmission ask for the calculated checksum on the other side they must be matched.

Comment: None of those are good solutions. In the CAN bus protocol, if a message is transmitted and no error are signaled then you are sure that your data has been sent and received.

Comment: there is two devices yes you are right but if we have  20 canbus devices. How can I determine the which canbus device couldnt catch message from the transmitter ?

Comment: if you have access to code on both sides and if the error is persisting it will eventually enter to bus off mode and probably causes an Interrupt. on the other hand, if the error is occasional you may print out the value of the counter for transmit Error and the receive Error in a parallel timer interrupt service routine.

Comment: I think the name of those two registers are REC and TEC.